# TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, autocompletetextview, android-textinputlayout

I'm using [`TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) in my Android app to achieve that neat floating label effect for my input fields. I know that I should be using the [`TextInputEditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html) as well to allow hints to be displayed when in landscape mode and the input are fills the entire screen.

However, in some of my input fields I have got autocompletion going on using [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) (which IMO has a really inconsistent name to it – “TextView” instead of “EditText” – but that's another story) and that obviously inherits directly from `EditText`. Thus it doesn't have the same functionality as `TextInputEditText` brings.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve the same hint-in-landscape functionality (without making my own `TextInputAutoCompleteTextView` implementation, that is) and to also avoid the lint warnings that are produced. Am I missing something here? I suppose I get that they didn't make custom versions of all direct and indirect subclasses of `EditText` for this specific thing, so am I expected to make my own?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A little late, but yes, you'll have to roll your own implementation.  The good news is that this is fairly straightforward.  Here's how `TextInputEditText` was implemented:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.java

Accordingly, here's what `TextInputAutoCompleteTextView` might look like.

```
public class TextInputAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    public TextInputAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextInputAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextInputAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        if (ic != null && outAttrs.hintText == null) {
            // If we don't have a hint and our parent is a TextInputLayout, use it's hint for the
            // EditorInfo. This allows us to display a hint in 'extract mode'.
            final ViewParent parent = getParent();
            if (parent instanceof TextInputLayout) {
                outAttrs.hintText = ((TextInputLayout) parent).getHint();
            }
        }
        return ic;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work with AndroidX's com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Comment: With AndroidX, use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` instead. See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753094/4568679

Comment: I used this solution but need to add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in this node to prevent an inflating error for the dropdown contents.

Answer (score 52):

Now, with AndroidX you don't need customise something.
Need just add material component style (was added in `1.1.0-alpha06`, see [release notes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha06)).

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Example TextInputLayout">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AutoCompleteTextView.FilledBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Not working, it says `Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AutoCompleteTextView.FilledBox'`. What am I doing wrong? I am using 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'.

Comment: Got it resolved, this style was added in 1.1.0-alpha06, see [release notes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha06)

Comment: Great! The OutlinedBox variant also works: `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox`. But Android Studio still does not provide auto-completion for both styles.

Answer (score 7):

Building off of chessdork's answer, I thought I'd go more into detail on how you can incorporate an autofill with a hint into your project. Here are the exact steps I used to get it working:

1) Make sure you have `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'` in your gradle dependencies. The exact package name be slightly different depending on your SDK version.

2) Copy the `TextInputAutoCompleteTextView` class from @chessdork's answer and put it in a public class within your project.

3) Place where you want the autofill edittext to be in your XML layout. It should be structured like this:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <mycompany.views.TextInputAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/myAutoFill"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/myHint"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

With the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) just use a [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) with a **`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu`** style.

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
     android:hint="Hint..."
     ...>

       <AutoCompleteTextView
           android:background="@null"
           .../>

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me using androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: Works for androidx.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers (@chessdork and @Shn_Android_Dev) help to achieve the correct behavior of an AutoCompleteTextView (ACTV) inside a TextInputLayout (TIL), however I found that there was no space between the start/end of the TIL and the ACTV inside of it as you can see in the following image:

[image: Example of how there is no space between the ACTV and the TIL]

What I did to solve the issue was to add a couple of padding values to the start and the end of the `TextInputAutoCompleteTextView`, the values that worked for me are 12dp at the beginning and 8dp at the end but of course you can play with that and get your desired effect. Taking @Shn_Android_Dev example, the `TextInputAutoCompleteTextView` would end up as:

```
<mycompany.views.TextInputAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/myAutoFill"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/myHint"/>
```

And the view now looks like this:

[image: Example with the correct spacing]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone needs the code for Xamarin Android implementation.

Here

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class TextInputAutoCompleteTextView : AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
    {
        public TextInputAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public TextInputAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        public TextInputAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context,
            attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
        }

        public override IInputConnection OnCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
        {
            IInputConnection ic = base.OnCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
            if (ic != null && outAttrs.HintText == null)
            {
                IViewParent parent = Parent;
                if (parent is TextInputLayout layout)
                {
                    outAttrs.HintText = new Java.Lang.String(layout.Hint);
                }
            }

            return ic;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Xml...

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <YourNamespace.TextInputAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/edtDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Movements"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

The easy solution is to cast your EditText to AutoCompleteTextView

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Java

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) textInputLayout.getEditText();
```